# Different colors for radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, radio-button

I want to style radion buttons this way:

[image]

The code I have right now looks like this:

```
input[type=radio] {
display:none;
}
input[type=radio]:checked +label:before {
background:green;
width: 15px;
height: 15px;
border: 0;
border-radius: 50%;
}
label {
color:black;
font-family:arial;
font-size:12px;
position:relative;
padding-left:20px;
}
label:hover {
color:green;
}
label:hover:before {
border:1px solid green;
border-radius: 50%;
}
label:before {
content:'';
height:13px;
width:13px;
border:1px solid lightgray;
border-radius: 50%;
display:inline-block;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
}
```

and the HTML-code:

```
<input id="kunstmuseum1" type="radio" name="kunstmuseum" onClick="animateKunst('voll')">    <label class="gruen" for="kunstmuseum1">Volle Subvention</label>
<input id="kunstmuseum2" type="radio" name="kunstmuseum" onClick="animateKunst('halb')"><label for="kunstmuseum2">Subventionen um die Hälfte kürzen</label>
<input id="kunstmuseum3" type="radio" name="kunstmuseum" checked="checked" onClick="animateKunst('null')"><label for="kunstmuseum3">Keine Subventionen mehr</label>
```

Is it possible to add different classes for input[type=radio] and how can I fill a radio button only half? Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x5d4tyq7/

Comment: when the radio button is half filled does it still selectable?

Comment: yes, it is only visual, also differences between the buttons, although i am not totally sure about the visuals. What i dont know is how to set different styles to radio buttons individually? For example: Same group of radio buttons but one is green, one orange and one red.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select the right radio button for the style use this css:

```
input[type=radio]:checked:nth-of-type(1) +label:before{
```

This will select the first radio button if its active. Change the nth-of-type(1) to any number to select the right radio button.

This changes the radio buttons to your examples:

Stripes:

```
  background: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(315deg, black, white 10%);
  background: -o-repeating-linear-gradient(315deg, black, white 10%);
  background: -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(315deg, black, white 10%);
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(315deg, black, white 10%);
```

50/50 black/white:

```
  background: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, black, black 49%, white 51%, white 100%);
  background: -o-repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, black, black 49%, white 51%, white 100%);
  background: -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, black, black 49%, white 51%, white 100%);
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, black, black 49%, white 51%, white 100%);
```

white:

```
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 1px green;
```

[Here is the JSfiddle with the working code.](http://jsfiddle.net/x5d4tyq7/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can fill the `before` with a linear gradient

```css
input[type=radio] {
    display:none;
}
input[type=radio]:checked +label:before {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, green 0%,green 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 51%, rgba(255, 255,255, 1) 100%);
    /* W3C */
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
label {
    color:black;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:12px;
    position:relative;
    padding-left:20px;
}
label:hover {
    color:green;
}
label:hover:before {
    border:1px solid green;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
label:before {
    content:'';
    height:13px;
    width:13px;
    border:1px solid lightgray;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

```html
<input id="kunstmuseum1" type="radio" name="kunstmuseum" onClick="animateKunst('voll')">
<label class="gruen" for="kunstmuseum1">Volle Subvention</label>
<input id="kunstmuseum2" type="radio" name="kunstmuseum" onClick="animateKunst('halb')">
<label for="kunstmuseum2">Subventionen um die Hälfte kürzen</label>
<input id="kunstmuseum3" type="radio" name="kunstmuseum" checked="checked" onClick="animateKunst('null')">
<label for="kunstmuseum3">Keine Subventionen mehr</label>
```

Comment: thanks, that's already great for the half filled button, but how can i style the three buttons differently? So that one button if clicked is completely filled, another one if clicked is half filled and for the third one only the border gets green.